# Overloaded << Operator Printing Address

Tags: c++, debugging, console, operator-overloading, ostream

**To the down-voters:** I understand that this was a poorly constructed question.  If you'll scroll down to the answers, you'll see that I discovered the source of the problem.  While the question itself might not be helpful, I hope the answer will help somebody experiencing similar trouble with operator overloading.  The problem was what it was; I cannot identify any edits or revisions that would make this a better question.  Therefore, if you're going to submit a down-vote, please add a constructive comment as well.  Thank you.

---

I'm running the following code

```
myObject o = myObject();
cout << o << endl;
```

My (`friend`) << operator is overloaded here:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& s, myObject o)
{
    s << doStuff(o, s) << endl;
    return s;
}
```

Expected output:

```
object contents
```

Actual output is, for some reason, including the memory address:

```
5452ED48object contents
```

Why?

Comment: What is `doStuff()`?  By the way.  Knock of all that "myObject o = myObject();" business.  "myObject o;" is sufficient.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: `myObject o` may not be sufficient if `myObject` is POD.

Comment: Not sufficient information, voting for closing.

Comment: It is usually a questionable practice to write endl inside your << operator: if the caller wants a new line, he'll add a new line (like you did).

Comment: `.doStuff()` is a recursive function to traverse a tree.  I didn't think it was relevant because the error appeared before I added the method.  I thought my problem might have a more general solution.  Perhaps I was wrong.  I will try to get an edit up soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not providing enough detail.  It turned out that I should have done this:

```
doStuff(o, s);
return s;
```

Apparently I was appending the desired output to `s`, which already contained the address.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot understand what you wanna do... I understood something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class obj{

    friend ostream&operator<<(ostream &out, const obj o);
public:
    obj(int a);
    int change_data();
private: 
    int s;
    int d;

};

obj::obj(int a)
{
    s = a;
    d = s;
}

int obj::change_data()
{
    return 99;
}

ostream&operator<<(ostream &out, const obj o){
    out << o.s;
    out << " ";
    out << o.d;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    obj some(1);
    cout << some;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 1 1

It seems to you have to learn about passing values by reference, because when you use the  "<< "operator overloading you do not return any value, you return values in the argument.